# Cypher MATCH, WHERE, REMOVE and WITH in right order for two separate relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to match a user by *id*, remove *ttl* properties from its (optional) address and get the related role(s) of the user.

The structure is

```
        (user)
       /      \
(address)  (role)
```

Do I need to use two queries for this? For now I have tried some options and I have read docs for `WHERE`, `REMOVE` and `WITH`.

Current status of query:

```
MATCH (user:USER) -[:HAS_FIRST_ADDRESS]-> (address:ADDRESS:TTL) WHERE ID(user) = 36
    WITH address REMOVE address.ttl REMOVE address:TTL,
    (user:USER) -[:HAS_ROLE]-> (role:ROLE) WHERE ID(user) = 36
    RETURN {user: user, role: role, address: address}
```

I am getting errors like

```
Invalid input 'W': expected whitespace, comment, a relationship pattern or '.' (line 1, column 177 (offset: 176))
```

Or for

```
MATCH (user:USER) -[:HAS_FIRST_ADDRESS]-> (address:ADDRESS:TTL) WHERE ID(user) = 3
    WITH address REMOVE address.ttl REMOVE address:TTL
    MATCH (user:USER) -[:HAS_ROLE]-> (role:ROLE) WHERE ID(user) = 36
    RETURN {user: user, role: role, address: address}
```

the error goes:

```
WITH is required between REMOVE and MATCH (line 1, column 136 (offset: 135))
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a `WITH` clause between `REMOVE` and `MATCH` as the error statement says:

```
MATCH (user:USER) -[:HAS_FIRST_ADDRESS]-> (address:ADDRESS:TTL) WHERE ID(user) = 3
WITH address REMOVE address.ttl REMOVE address:TTL
WITH address
MATCH (user:USER) -[:HAS_ROLE]-> (role:ROLE) WHERE ID(user) = 36
RETURN {user: user, role: role, address: address}
```